# Why is my Ubuntu 22.10 screen have no-icon marks all around?

Tags: gnome, 22.10

I've Installed Ubuntu 22.10 on my Dell Inspiron 3595 dualbooted with Windows 10. There were all icons at first. Then, I began noticing some no-icon marks around my desktop but I'm not sure what was the cause.

[image: Please click me for proof]

[image: More Proof]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have there been any customisations to the desktop, such as icon packs, themes, or other packages being installed?

Comment: No, I just saw it yesterday itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Icon cache might have been corrupted, a simple update can sometimes cause the cache to be corrupted,  try rebuilding the cache using

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/
```

if this doesn't work, try resetting the desktop environment using

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

if any above options don't work,uninstall the default icon pack, and re-installing the default icon pack.

Comment: Ok, but how do I do the 3rd Option?

Comment: assuming you are using ubuntu-mono-dark you can remove it using `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-mono-dark` if you are not sure which one you are using you can use `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme`

Comment: If still not working try to change the icon pack.

Comment: Yes, but how to reinstall the icon theme

Comment: replace `remove` with `install`

Comment: And what about it says ' Drive letter: Unable to locate package Yaru-blue

Comment: `sudo apt remove yaru-theme-icon`

Comment: Nevermind, I reinstalled Ubuntu